# How do I make a div invisible by hovering over text link?

Tags: html, css

How would I make a div visible when I hover over a text link. I am making a nav bar and want something show when the mouse is hovering over the link. How do I do so. I want to use the css visibility.

CSS Code

```
.contentmenubutton:hover{
text-decoration: none;
```

}

HTML code:

```
<a href="#" class="contentmenubutton">
  <div id="hoverbar"></div>
  <div class="textnav">Testing</div>
</a>
```

Comment: I added the code I had made so far

Comment: Are you planning on using jQuery?

Comment: It does not matter. I would like to use jQuery

Answer (score 4):

A way to do this:
Set the div's visibility to hidden by default.
When hovering over the link, the div will be shown.

HTML

```
<a href="#">Text</a>
<div></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: green;
    visibility: hidden;
}

a:hover + div {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e2xm8jdn/).

Note: In the title you say you want the div to become **invisible**, in the post you say you want it to become **visible**. Be aware of that next time.

If you want that the div becomes invisible, when hovering over a link:

Simply make sure that the div is visible by default (it already is, you don't need CSS for that). And change visible to hidden, like this:

```
a:hover + div {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript (in this example jQuery), you can achieve this by using the jQuery hover method like this:

**HTML**

```
// A link to hover
<a href="#" id="toggleDivVisibility">Testing</a>
// A div to hide once link is hovered
<div id="divHiddenUntilHover">im invisible when contentmenubutton is hovered</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// Wait for dom to be ready
$(function () {
    // Make use of the hover method, pass it two anonymous functions
    $('#toggleDivVisibility').hover(function() {
        // First function: triggers when hovered.
        $('#divHiddenUntilHover').hide();
    }, function() {
        // Second function triggers when mouse leaves the element.
        $('#divHiddenUntilHover').show();
    });
});
```

**None jQuery example:**

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="foo">
    This is some anchor element
</a>
<div id="bar">
    This div will hide when element with id of 'foo' is hovered
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var elementToHover = document.getElementById('foo'),
    elementToHide = document.getElementById('bar');

elementToHover.addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
    elementToHide.style.display = "none";
});
elementToHover.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
    elementToHide.style.display = "block";
});
```

Comment: This is way too complicated for such a request. You should never introduce JavaScript for something that is natively handled by CSS.

Comment: I agree on that in this particular exercise.